# Union of subspaces in $ \mathcal P_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $\mathcal P_n$ be a vector space of all real polynomials of degree $\leq n,\;n\geq2$$\&\;\;\;t_1,t_2\in \mathbb R,\;t_1\ne t_2.$

We are observing $M\leq P_n$

$$M_i=\{p_i\in \mathcal P_n: p_i(t_i)=0, i=1,2\}$$

Prove that:

$(\forall p\in \mathcal P_n)(\exists p_1, p_2\in P_n) \;p=p_1+p_2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$M_1\cap M_2=\{0\}$ and $\underset{i=1,2}{\dot\bigcup} M_i=\mathcal P_n$